# Selenium grid - spread 1000 tests on 3 machins

Tags: selenium, grid, load-balancing

- I have 1000 Seleneses to launch
- I have 3 servers

Is it possible with Selenium Grid to load balance the text executions on the 3 servers (each test is a different one) ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's what Selenium Grid is about. You can launch as many test servers as you want and connect them to the Grid.

Then launch your tests against the Grid and it will dispatch them to your servers transparently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Identify a master VM/server which acts as the hub.
Connect your 3 servers as nodes.

The hub connects to the nodes and runs tests on them in parallel, you need to leverage parallel/multi-thread mode by using TestNG if you're working on Java.

Selenium Grid loads your servers one after the other, if server1 already has 4 tests runnning and even though server2 is fully idle, Se Grid sends the next test to server1. After server1 reaches it's maximum capacity, then the next test is sent to server2 until it reaches it's max capacity and so forth. You can control all this if you implement a prioritizer in your framework though.